# How to implement clickListener at Osmdroid?

Tags: android, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I like to implement similar method of Google Map's `onMapClick(LatLng arg)` at Osmdroid. What I did was

```
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {

        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);        
    }
```

But `dispatchTouchEvent` is called multiple times when the map is clicked only one time. How can I implement similar method of Google Map at Osmdroid?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OSMBonusPack [MapEventsOverlay](http://code.google.com/p/osmbonuspack/source/browse/trunk/OSMBonusPack/src/org/osmdroid/bonuspack/overlays/MapEventsOverlay.java) and MapEventsReceiver.

Answer (score 0):

MKer's response is correct. But I like to update another solution. We can set limit using

```
if(ev.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
{
}
```

so that there is only single call on dispatchTouchEvent{}.